# Django: Get User profile from User serializer

Tags: python, django

I have a basic ‍‍‍‍`UserProfile` model that has a `OneToOne` relationship with a `User` model.

My User serializer works well, though how do I go about retrieving the related `UserProfile` model from the same serializer and `viewset`?

**Here is my UserProfile Model:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    cellphone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    useraccount = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**My current viewset:**

```
class CurrentUserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CurrentUserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        queryset = User.objects.filter(username = user)
        return queryset
```

**My User serializer:**

```
class CurrentUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups')

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        return {
            'username': instance.username,
            'email': instance.email,
            'first_name': instance.first_name,
            'last_name': instance.last_name,
            'groups':  GroupSerializer(instance.groups.all(), many=True).data,
        }
```

I attempted the following with my Serializers, but got an attribute error stating that my User model does not have the field `profile`:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('dashboards', 'fullname')

class CurrentUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    profile = TeamMemberDashboardSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups', 'profile')

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        return {
            'username': instance.username,
            'email': instance.email,
            'first_name': instance.first_name,
            'last_name': instance.last_name,
            'groups':  GroupSerializer(instance.groups.all(), many=True).data,
            'profile': instance.profile
        }
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: According to your models the field is called `userprofile` and not `profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put, for **showing** profile data is to put `depth = 1` in `class Meta` of your serializer as follows:

```
class CurrentUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups')
        depth = 1 

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        return {
            'username': instance.username,
            'email': instance.email,
            'first_name': instance.first_name,
            'last_name': instance.last_name,
            'groups':  GroupSerializer(instance.groups.all(), many=True).data,
        }
```